# Cannot go through npm audit with uglify-js related vulnerablities

Tags: node.js, npm, uglifyjs

I am new in node js. Recently I run npm install and get several vulnerabilities warning. My uglifyjs version is 2.8.26. I tried to update it to uglify@3 but I still cannot run through it. PLease help me.

```
$npm install              
audited 244 packages in 1.212s
found 2 low severity vulnerabilities
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

$npm audit


                   === npm audit security report ===
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpxu2.png)

Comment: Did you try  "npm audit fix"?

Comment: @desoares Yes, I did. But it shows "2 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated"

Comment: @desoares I find that if I update uglifyjs with commend 
    sudo npm install uglify-js@latest -g 
and use 
sudo npm install to run the server. It works. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: The solution I have found so far is to downgrade NPM or replace tho "unsecure" packages.

Comment: @desoares You're right. My npm version for root is v5.8.0 :\